# SweetAlert2 doesn't recognize my Animate.css class

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css, sweetalert2

So I'm trying to put my own CSS class to use with SweetAlert2. Everything is OK with the code in terms of syntax or something. It just simply doesn't work, my CSS class is not being recognized by the SweetAlert JS object.

Here's my code:

**index.js**

```js
const Toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: "top",
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 2000,
  animation: false,
  customClass: {
    inDown: "animated bounceInDown"
  }
});
```

And now the index.css file, which contains the animation + class definition:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from,
  60%,
  75%,
  90%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.bounceInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}
```

and in the base.html I have the  tag like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.17.6/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

What's wrong? why isn't it working?

Comment: The object with class bounceInDown have class animated too or is inside object with animated class?

Comment: OMG. you're right. I forgot to add the .animated class. thanks Germano

Comment: it still doesn't work.. although i added the .animated class
EDIT: IT WORKS, HAD TO CHANGE "inDown" to "popup".